# How do I translate my application name that is shown on the user profile page or in my application profile page?

Tags: facebook, translation

How do I translate my application name that is shown on the user profile page or in my application profile page?

I have tried to use the facebook translation service, but it does not work.

Comment: can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes it seem like you can translate the name of your application and the translations will show through out Facebook.  The translation application has been broken since inception.

Here's a bug that's well over a year old about this issue:  http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10501

I have seen some application re-publishing under other names (under different languages) to help capture users who use those languages.  I have no idea what Facebook's stance is on that practice, though.